# My iOS application's picture is strange and broken?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, app-store

I was confused by this problem. Can anyone help me?
It occurs whether I download it from App Store or run it in my iPhone 5s by Xcode, but it is all right when I use iPhone simulator and other iPhone(etc iPhone 6, 6s, 7, 8, X).
Here is my snapshot with this problem.

**Snapshot:**

[image]

And here is my iPhone status.

**iPhone 5s - About iPhone:**

[image]

Comment: Is it your App? If yes, please show the related codes.

Comment: go to interface builder>show the attribute inspector>view set your imageview Aspect fit

Comment: @Raptor All images was be set like this -- attch.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"down"]; and image's format is png. It's all right in other iPhone but not this iPhone 5s.

Comment: @JRB  I write codes without xib or storyboard. and make attributes by Masonry.

Comment: @the4kman thx a lot. I think it’s the same bug with Xcode 9.2